# Best way to remove and replace different characters from multiple filenames?

Tags: linux, regular-expression, perl, rename

I have several folders full of files with the following format:

```
Show Name - 07x09 - Episode Title.mp4
```

What I'm trying to do is rename them to the following format:

```
Show.Name.S07E09.Episode.Title.mp4
```

I've already accomplished this using a few rename commands:

```
rename 's/ - /./g' *
rename 's/ /./g' *
rename 's/.([0-9]+)x([0-9])/.S$1E$2/g' *
```

But I know there must be a better, more efficient way. How would you tackle this?

Comment: No, the idea was to remove the spaces and hyphens and have only periods as separators, then change the format of  Season Number x Episode Number to SXXEXX. The actual words that make up the show name and episode titles aren't important and don't need to be treated in any special way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
rename -n -v 's/[- ]+/./g; s/([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)/S$1E$2/' ./*.mp4
```

if its result was what you wanted, remove the `-n` option to rename your files.

---

Demo:

```
rename(./Sh  ow Name -  07x09 - Episode Title.mp4, ./Sh.ow.Name.S07E09.Episode.Title.mp4)
rename(./Sh  ow Name - 07x09 - Episode Title.mp4, ./Sh.ow.Name.S07E09.Episode.Title.mp4)
rename(./Sh  ow Name-  07x09 - Episode Title.mp4, ./Sh.ow.Name.S07E09.Episode.Title.mp4)
rename(./Sh  ow Name- -  07x09 - Episode Title.mp4, ./Sh.ow.Name.S07E09.Episode.Title.mp4)
rename(./Sh  ow Name- \---  07x09 - Episode Title.mp4, ./Sh.ow.Name.\.S07E09.Episode.Title.mp4)
rename(./Sh  ow Name--  07x09 - Episode Title.mp4, ./Sh.ow.Name.S07E09.Episode.Title.mp4)
rename(./Show Name - 07x09 - Episode Title.mp4, ./Show.Name.S07E09.Episode.Title.mp4)
```